# Random scan Gibbs sampling as special case of Metropolis-Hastings

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, gibbs, mcmc-acceptance-rate

I am reading Blitzstein's Introduction to Probability and come across with the following proof that I don't really understand:

Theorem: The random scan Gibbs sampler is a special case of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, in which the proposal is always accepted. In particular, it follows that the stationary distribution of the random scan Gibbs sampler is as desired.

Proof: We will show this in two dimensions and the proof is similar in any dimension. Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables whose joint PMF is the desired stationary distribution. Let's work out what the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm says to do: using the following proposal distribution: from $(x,y)$, randomly update one coordinate by running one move of the random scan Gibbs sampler.

To simplify notation, write
$P(X=x,Y=y)=p(x,y), P(Y=y|X=x)=p(y|x), P(X=x|Y=y)=p(x|y)$.
More formally, we should write $p_{Y|X}(y|x)$ instead of $p(y|x)$ to avoid issues like wondering what $p(5|3)$ means. But writing $p(y|x)$ is more compact and does not create ambiguity in this proof.

Let's compute the Metropolis-Hastings acceptance probability for going from $(x,y)$ to $(x',y')$. The states $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ must be equal in at least one component since the proposal says to update only one component. Suppose $x=x'$ (the case $y=y'$ can be handled symmetrically). Then the acceptance probability is

$$\frac{p(x,y')p(y|x)\frac{1}{2}}{p(x,y)p(y'|x)\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{p(x)p(y'|x)p(y|x)}{p(x)p(y|x)p(y'|x)}=1$$
and the result follows.  Q.E.D.

I have two questions about the above proof:

1. How did the author directly write the ratio of the proposal distribution as $(p(y|x)\frac{1}{2})/(p(y'|x)\frac{1}{2})$? Because by definition, the ratio of the proposal distribution is equal to

$$\frac{p(y|y',x)}{p(y'|y,x)}=\frac{\frac{p(y,x|y')}{p(x|y')}}{\frac{p(y',x|y)}{p(x|y)}}=\frac{\frac{p(y|x)p(x)}{p(y)}}{\frac{p(y'|x)p(x)}{p(y')}}\cdot \frac{\frac{p(x,y,y')}{p(y')}}{\frac{p(x,y,y')}{p(y)}}=\frac{p(y|x)}{p(y'|x)}$$

So my calculation agrees with the author's but I don't understand how he could just write it out directly. Is there any way to see it directly instead of undergoing a rather messy calculation?

2. What is the factor $(1/2)/(1/2)$? I don't understand why we have to multiply a factor of $1/2$ to the proposal distribution.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Presumably $\frac12$ for the random choice of which component to update in *random scan*